Passing a dictionary in Azure DevOps pipeline templates
In an Azure DevOps pipeline template I need to pass variables as a dictionary to another template which will use an ansible task to process all keys in the dictionary.
The type: object seems appropriate, but I'm looking for a working example.
main-template.yml
trigger:
- main

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: DeployJob
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - template: ansible-template.yml
      parameters:
        ansibleVars:
          var1: value1
          var2: value2


ansible-template.yml
parameters:
- name: ansibleVars
  type: object
  default: {}

jobs:
- job: AnsibleJob
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.x'
      addToPath: true

  - script: |
      python -m pip install ansible-core
    displayName: 'Install Ansible'

  - script: |
      echo "${{ parameters.ansibleVars  }}" > vars.yml
    displayName: 'Create vars file'

  - task: Ansible@0
    displayName: 'Run playbook'
    inputs:
      ansibleInterface: 'agentMachine'
      playbookPathOnAgentMachine: './ansible/playbook.yml'
      inventoriesAgentMachine: 'file'
      inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: './ansible/inventory/hosts'
      args: -vv -e @vars.yaml
    failOnStdErr: false


Can you show us some code to better illustrate the problem? For example, how you pretend to use the Ansible task?

According to the documentation, you can use vars from a JSON or YAML file:
ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "@some_file.json"
ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "@some_file.yaml"

In your pipeline you can use convertToJson to convert a parameter to a json string and then generate a json file and use it in your Ansible@0 task.
Example
parameters:
  - name: ansibleVars
    type: object
    default:
      version: 1.0.0
      other_varialbe: foo
  - name: varsFile
    type: string
    default: $(Agent.TempDirectory)/ansible-vars.json

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - script: |
      echo ${ANSIBLE_VARS} > ${ANSIBLE_VARS_FILE}
      cat ${ANSIBLE_VARS_FILE}
    displayName: Create json variables file
    env:
      ANSIBLE_VARS_FILE: ${{ parameters.varsFile }}
      ANSIBLE_VARS: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.ansibleVars) }}
  
  - task: Ansible@0
    displayName: 'Run playbook'
    inputs:
      ansibleInterface: 'agentMachine'
      playbookPathOnAgentMachine: './ansible/playbook.yml'
      inventoriesAgentMachine: 'file'
      inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: './ansible/inventory/hosts'
      args: -vv -e @${{ parameters.varsFile }}  # <-------------- use generated json file
    failOnStdErr: false

Please note I'm assigning the json string to a task environment variable instead of using it directly in the script body - this way I don't need to bother escaping quotes and other special characters:
  - script: |
      # ...
    env:
      ANSIBLE_VARS: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.ansibleVars) }}


You can reference the sample below to pass dictionary into the template YAML:

The template YAML

# templates/steps.yml

parameters:
- name: vars
  type: object
  default: []

steps:
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "var1 = $env:var1"
    Write-Host "var2 = $env:var2"
    Write-Host "var3 = $env:var3"
  displayName: 'Show all vars'
  env:
    ${{ parameters.vars }}

- ${{ each var in parameters.vars }}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Key = ${{ var.Key }}"
      Write-Host "Value = ${{ var.Value }}"
    displayName: 'Show var - ${{ var.Key }}'


The main YAML.

# azure-pipelines.yml

steps:
- template: templates/steps.yml
  parameters:
    vars:
      var1: valu1
      var2: valu2
      var3: valu3



If you want to pass all the key-value pairs to the args field of the Ansible@0 task, you can set the template like as below.
# templates/steps.yml

parameters:
- name: vars
  type: object
  default: []

steps:
- powershell: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=argVar;]empty"
  displayName: 'Set argVar'

- ${{ each var in parameters.vars }}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Key = ${{ var.Key }}"
      Write-Host "Value = ${{ var.Value }}"
      if ("$(argVar)" -ne "empty" ) {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=argVar;]$(argVar) ${{ var.Key }}=${{ var.Value }}"
      }
      else {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=argVar;]${{ var.Key }}=${{ var.Value }}"
      }
    displayName: 'Show var - ${{ var.Key }}'

- powershell: Write-Host "$(argVar)"
  displayName: 'Show var argVar'

- task: Ansible@0
  displayName: 'Run playbook'
  inputs:
    playbookPathOnAgentMachine: path/to/playbook.yml
    inventoriesAgentMachine: file
    inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: path/to/hosts
    args: '$(argVar)'



